# Error in Validate Field with ACF plugin in Wordpress

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, validation, 500-internal-error

I have the following problem when I am validating a field with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in wordpress. What happens is that the field is validated correctly but the error appears on a new page instead of going out on the same page above the field to which I am validating. The code to validate is the following:

```
function validate_fields_contact()
{
    add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=phone_contact', 'validate_phone_number', 10, 4);
}

function validate_phone_number($valid, $value, $field, $input)
{
    if (!$valid) {
        return $valid;
    }

    if(!preg_match("/^\+XX(\s|\d){8,12}$/", $value)) {
        return __('Incorrect Format.');
    }

    return true;
}
```

**It should be like that:**

[image]

**This is what happens**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did have the same issue. And I wasted enough time for the answer.

At first be sure that:

The ajax request isn't failed and happens. So, check:

1. Is acf_form_head() before get_header() and run before any html is output?
2. Does your theme contain call to wp_head()?
3. Does your theme contain call to wp_foot()?
4. Are your deferring the loading of JavaScript or otherwise altering the way that JavaScript is loaded on the page?

(Look at [this ACF support topic](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/my-acf_form-is-saving-to-the-database-but-not-showing-up-in-the-admin-panel-unde/) too. If you use acf_form() for creating new user look at [this topic](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/create-new-user-with-acf_form/)).

But in my case the root was is_admin() in this line into the 'acf/validate_value' hook:

```
if ( ! $valid || is_admin() ) { return $valid; }
```

**Because is_admin() returns 'true' by AJAX requests**. As a result, the validate function didn't work.

Hope it will helpfully for somebody.

Comment: thanks for the answer, a while ago I had already solved the problem but I had forgotten to answer it here, my problem was that I was calling validation in a method that was executed before the header of the site and that's why I thought about it in the question, thanks for the reply again and the vote as accepted, greetings

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this later -- in my case it was because I had an `admin_init` hook to prevent access to `wp-admin` for a certain role (which is why we usually have a front end ACF form anyway right?) and it would produce an error when trying to run `admin-ajax.php`. ACF uses that file for AJAX validation so when you run some sort of "prevent wp-admin" hook, that stops ACF validation, too.

So, the hook interfering was:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_no_admin_access', 100 );
function custom_no_admin_access() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    if($user_role === 'special-role'){
        exit( wp_redirect(home_url()));
    }
}
```

and I turned it into:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_no_admin_access', 100 );
function custom_no_admin_access() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    if($user_role === 'special-role' && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'){
        exit( wp_redirect(home_url()));
    }
}
```

A big help for troubleshooting was using Chrome's Inspector to track the network requests. Go to the Network tab and check "Preserve Log" so you can see the history of requests.  Try to submit the form and I could see it was redirecting to the home page (which my `admin_init` hook says to do when attempting to use admin-ajax.php) before failing the validation.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Two days searching for the fix to the same problem... It looks like the `acf_form_head()` is not necessary in the validation and the error, in my case, is there. So I add this `if` and the magic happened.

```
function acf_inscs_head () {
    if ( !wp_doing_ajax() ) // avoid to load acf_form_head() on validation
        acf_form_head();
}
add_action( 'init', 'acf_inscs_head', -1 );
```